# How to iterate through a map of Objects in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this data as json:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "value":"value x",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option d"
   },
   "attachment":null,
   "price":0
},
{
   "id":2,
   "value":"value y",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option b"
   },
   "attachment":null,
   "price":0
},
```

I wanted to view them as ListView after grouping them with Option.name so the return is a map as:

```
Map<String, List<Option>> getGrouped(
      List<Option> options) {
    Map<String, List<Option>> groupByData = groupBy(
        itemVariations, (obj) => (obj as Option).option.name);
    return groupByData;
  }
```

I am not how can this be viewed as a nested Text() widget?
I tried many things and its always:

```
The argument type 'List<Option>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

Comment: Is it you getting in the array []..Post your whole response

Comment: What are you defining 'Option' as?  The json itself look like List<Map<String,dynamic>>  even the option piece is a Map, not a List.

Comment: Could you update your question about how you want your data to look?  I think it would help formulate an answer.  I'm still not 100% certain about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @William Terrill, Option is an object {id,  name}. And that's not an array when I get it in the json. It's just one whole object. I need to group the Options by their names (option d or option b) I am successfully grouping them but I cant iterate through the map which is a nested list of Options and then values. So I go thru the Options and out put them as a list then go through the values as another nested list. I need to output widgets for each item in the list/map.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'll answer the question as posed first, however I wanted to put forward a different way of approaching this problem:

In order to iterate through a map, you have to get the map keys, and then iterate through the keys, using them to access the map. Here's an example:

```
Map<String,String> testMap = {"first":"1st","second":"2nd", "third":"3rd"};

main(){
  for (String key in testMap.keys){
    print(key);
    print(testMap[key]);
  }
}
```

here's a dartpad with the above example: https://dartpad.dev/8c342ae34d34b5572795a4b8bc60e1b6

However, I'm guessing that you don't need to do that.

But first, some information.

In your comments, I asked what you were defining 'option' as.  The reason I asked this is because you put List in your code.  The <> denotes a variable type, not a Map key. Also, capital letters in Dart are considered class names.  Therefore, when I read your code, I assumed that you had done something like this:

```
class MyOption {     //<-- this defines the class MyOption
  final int id;
  final String name;
}

MyOption ex1 = MyOption(1, "option a");  // <-- these define objects ex1, ex2 
MyOption ex2 = MyOption(2, "option b");  // <-- you can defined these as 'MyOption' 
                                         // types because you defined the 
                                         // MyOption class.

List<MyOption> myList = [ex1,ex2];  // this is a list of Option object.
```

so, the reason that you are getting the "argument type List can't be assigned to the parameter 'string' is because you're mixing types of variable. (specifically String and List)

Second, it's hard to tell, but I'm not convinced that you are handling the  decoded json.  You need to do this before you start manipulating it in flutter.  In order to do that you need to do something like this:

```
var jsonStr = """   // <-- the json data you get should look like this:
{
  "results": [
    {
   "id":1,             
   "value":"value x",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option d"
   },
   "attachment":null,
   "price":0
},
    {
   "id":2,
   "value":"value y",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option b"
   },
   "attachment":null,
   "price":0
}
  ]
}
""";

main() {


  Map<String, dynamic> myMap = jsonDecode(jsonStr); // decode json here
```

And therefore, we can iterate through the array in the normal way

```
  print("Values from json data:");
  for(int i=0; i<myMap['results'].length; i++){
    print(myArray[i]['option']['name']);
  }
}
```

I made a dartpad with this 2nd set of code so you can play around with it:

https://dartpad.dev/7f670e3835ad292f2b325dd3d40bb41c

Please let me know if this helps, and I'll update my answer with anything I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

this is a working code.
It prints a ListView by option name like this:

[image: list view by option name]

I hope it can help you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "dart:convert";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  static String json = """[{
   "id":1,
   "value":"value x",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option d"
   },
   "attachment":"a",
   "price":0
},
{
   "id":2,
   "value":"value y",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option b"
   },
   "attachment":"b",
   "price":0
},
{
   "id":3,
   "value":"value z",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option b"
   },
   "attachment":"b",
   "price":0
},
{
   "id":3,
   "value":"value h",
   "option":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"option b"
   },
   "attachment":"b",
   "price":0
}]""";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Options> list = List<Options>.from(
      jsonDecode(json).map((x) => Options.fromJson(x))
    );

    Map<String, List<Options>> mymap = Map<String, List<Options>>();

    list.forEach((option){
      print(option.option.name);
      if (!mymap.containsKey(option.option.name)) {  
        mymap[option.option.name] = List<Options>();
      }
      mymap[option.option.name].add(option);
    });

    print(mymap.keys.length);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: mymap.length,
      itemBuilder: 
        (_, index) {
          String key = mymap.keys.toList()[index];
          return Text("$key ${mymap[key].map((o)=>o.value)}");
        }
    ),),
    );
  }

}

class Options {
    final int id;
    final String value;
    final Option option;
    final dynamic attachment;
    final int price;

    Options({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.value,
        @required this.option,
        @required this.attachment,
        @required this.price,
    });

    factory Options.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Options(
        id: json["id"],
        value: json["value"],
        option: Option.fromJson(json["option"]),
        attachment: json["attachment"],
        price: json["price"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "value": value,
        "option": option.toJson(),
        "attachment": attachment,
        "price": price,
    };
}

class Option {
    final int id;
    final String name;

    Option({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.name,
    });

    factory Option.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Option(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please run the given below code in **DartPad** and get output it will be helpful  for you

```
void main() {Map<String, dynamic> sam =  {'A' : {
'name' : 'Will',
'age' : 60 },'B' : {
'name' : 'Smith',
'age' : 57 }};sam['A'].remove('name');print(sam);}
```